# how to make json parsing with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, iphone, json, afnetworking

Hi iam trying to implement AFNetworking Framework. I want to retrive json data using AFNetworking framework. But i have no idea of how to retrive json data using AFNetworking framework. Please any body guide me.
This is my code:

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad

{

    userid=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"user_id"];

    encryptpwd=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"Encrypt_Psw"];

    id=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"comm_id"];

    NSString *strJson=[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"userId=%@&encryptPassword=%@&commId=%@",userid,encryptpwd,id];

    NSString *strlength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[strJson length]];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@“My URL”];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

   [request addValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

   [request addValue:strlength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

   NSData *requestData=[strJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   [request setHTTPBody:requestData];

   [request setHTTPMethod:@"Post"];

   [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

{

     responseData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

{

    [responseData appendData:data];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;

    NSError *err;

    NSString *strResponse=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"response is %@",strResponse);

    dit=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];

    NSArray *arrResults = [dit valueForKey:@"class_mst"];

    listOfObjects = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(dictRes in arrResults)

    {

         Attributes *at = [[Attributes alloc]init];

         at.classimage=[dictRes valueForKey:@"image_name"];

         at.classname=[dictRes valueForKey:@"class_title"];

         [listOfObjects addObject:at];

    }

    [tableView reloadData];

 }


 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error

{

     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;

     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection" message:@"Please ensure you have internet connection" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

     [alert show];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

    return [listOfObjects count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

     static NSString *identifier=@"cell";

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) 

    {

         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier];

    }

    UIImageView *imageView =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 80)];

    imageView.tag = 100;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];

    UILabel *classtitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 120, 200, 20)];

    classtitle.highlightedTextColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    classtitle.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:classtitle];

    Attributes *att = [listOfObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *strf=att.classname;

    classtitle.text=strf;

    str=att.classimage;

    url=@“image URL”;

     UIImageView *cellImageView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];

   // cellImageView.image = nil;

   if(str!=nil) 

   {

        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

       dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) 

       {


            NSString *imageStr = [url stringByAppendingString:str];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageStr]]];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            cellImageView.image = image;

       });

       });

    }

    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can import AFNetworking library from below link:https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking
and use below code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"YOURURL"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 NSString *strJson=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userId=%@&encryptPassword=%@&commId=%@",userid,encryptpwd,id];
[request setHTTPBody:[strJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:JSON];

    NSArray *arrResults = [dict valueForKey:@"class_mst"];

    listOfObjects = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(dictRes in arrResults)

    {

     Attributes *at = [[Attributes alloc]init];

     at.classimage=[dictRes valueForKey:@"image_name"];

     at.classname=[dictRes valueForKey:@"class_title"];

     [listOfObjects addObject:at];

   }

   [tableView reloadData];
```

} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){
    }];

```
[operation start];
```

Comment: thanks for your response.According to my code remaining part same or any changes are there in my code.i mean - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection those part is same or any changes are there?

Comment: i got error, like "use of undeclared identifier" this line of code..AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)......... what type of class imported my .m file

Comment: The way you pass parameters isn't correct. You should decide whether you are passing JSON as content or form-urlencoded parameters.

Comment: @Shubham, i got error only that line of code brother.And iam importe #import "AFNetworking.h"

Comment: @Shubham i got error like "use of undeclared identifier AFJsonRequestOperation"

Answer (score 0):

In AFNetworking you can you AFJSONRequestOperation, It fetch data across the network and give the pasred json response. Thanks

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

            //it give parse json data
            NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:JSON];

        } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {

        }];

        [operation start];
```